# Convert string.Split(',') into array of int

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3, split

I have the following string:

`"2,26,17,33,6,14,9,29,1"`

And an array of `int`, `usedIds`.

If I do:

```
private var usedIds:Array;
usedIds = "2,26,17,33,6,14,9,29,1".split(',');
```

I get an array of `strings`.

How can I do it to get an array of `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var string:String = "2,26,17,33,6,14,9,29,1";

            var strings:Array = string.split(',');

            var ints:Array = new Array();

            for each(var s:String in strings)
            {
                ints.push(int(s));

            }// end for each

            trace(ints[0]) // output: 2
            trace(ints[0] is int) // output: true

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

**[UPDATE]**

A slightly shorter version of the above is:

```
var string:String = "2,26,17,33,6,14,9,29,1";

var ints:Array = new Array();

for each(var s:String in string.split(","))
{
    ints.push(int(s));

}// end for each

trace(ints[0]) // output: 2
trace(ints[0] is int) // output: true
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

Shortest(don't recommend):

```
var ints:Array = [];

for each(var s:String in "2,26,17,33,6,14,9,29,1".split(",")) ints.push(int(s));

trace(ints[0]) // output: 2
trace(ints[0] is int) // output: true
```

Comment: I had tested and found I needed to change to an almost identical answer, so +1 for you!  One thing though, defining an empty array with `var array:Array = [];` is more efficent than `new Array()`

Comment: @shanethehat thanks for array literal over `new Array()` tip.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is using Linq:

```
int[] usedIds = "2,26,17,33,6,14,9,29,1".split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Another case of the simplest answer being the best... Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

An other example :

```
var a:Array = "2,26,17,33,6,14,9,29,1".split(",");
a.forEach(function(item:*, index:int, array:Array):void{
   array[index] = int(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to loop through your array and convert it (tested):

```
function splitToInt($input:String,$delimiter:String):Array
{
    var inArr:Array = $input.split($delimiter);
    var outArr:Array = [];
    for each(var index in inArr) {
        trace(index);
        outArr.push(int(index));
    }
    return outArr;  
}

var usedIds:Array = splitToInt("2,26,17,33,6,14,9,29,1",",");
```

Comment: +1 for encapsulating the logic for converting the `String` elements into `int` elements.